# Upload a photo to multiple pages on Facebook, using graphi API batch request

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, batch-processing

I have done a lot of searching for the answer, but I am unable to find one.

I am trying to upload a single photo to numerous facebook pages, using the graph API.

Using an answer from a similar question I am able to get what I need to do working, like this;

```
curl 
 –F  'access_token=…' \
 -F  'batch=[{"method":"POST", \
          "relative_url":"me/photos", \
          "body":"message=Photo" \
          "attached_files":"file1" \
         },
         {"method":"POST", \
          "relative_url":"me/photos", \
          "body":"message=Photo" \
          "attached_files":"file2" \
         },
        ]’
 -F  'file1=@/tmp/photo.gif' \
 -F  'file2=@/tmp/photo.gif' \
https://graph.facebook.com
```

This means that for every page I want to post the photo to, I have to upload a duplicate of the photo. What I want to do is something like this;

```
curl 
 –F  'access_token=…' \
 -F  'batch=[{"method":"POST", \
          "relative_url":"me/photos", \
          "body":"message=Photo" \
          "attached_files":"file" \
         },
         {"method":"POST", \
          "relative_url":"me/photos", \
          "body":"message=Photo" \
          "attached_files":"file" \
         },
        ]’
 -F  'file=@/tmp/photo.gif' \
https://graph.facebook.com
```

This doesn't appear to work, one photo will be uploaded, the other requests in the batch will return an error message;

```
{"error":{"message":"(#1) An unknown error occurred","type":"OAuthException","code":1}}
```

If I have to attach the same photo to the batch request, one per request. I may as well not use the batch request and just do one request for each page I want to upload the photo to.

Anybody know what the problem is?

Comment: Some things to check: 1) Does your `access_token` have the rights to publish a photo to all these pages? 2) Are you using the relative_url `/me/photos` for all the batch requests? Only one page will be `me` in the context of your access_token, so you'll be attempting to post the same photo multiple times to the same page.

Comment: I am using my own page just for testing. I am able to post multiple photos to my own page when I add the same photo under different names in the main request. When I add only 1 photo, one gets posted and the others give the error message.

Comment: I don't think Facebook is going to allow you to post the same photo multiple times to a single page in one API call. You can create additional pages with visibility set to "admins only" if you want to test this.

Comment: Take a good look at the Facebook TOS before you release this. Your app sounds like a spam app in Facebook's eyes.

Comment: I think I didn't make the question clear. I want to post the picture to multiple pages, or groups. In the example I am using "/me/photos" so I don't spam groups while testing. I guess I will have to upload the same photo numerous times, one per group/page I'm posting to. I just hoped there was a way to avoid this.

Comment: Your question is clear, but your test isn't. Create a couple of private pages and use these to test your app so you're not trying to post the same photo over and over again to a single page and you're not spamming someone else's page.

Comment: I tested this on some private pages. Same result. Posts to one of them but no more. I guess there is a one to one relationship between attached files and requests.